# Get all ancestors of current node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I want to get all ancestors of current node:

[image]

XML:

```
<root>
   <item title="a">
       <item title="b">               
           <item title="c"></item> <!--CURRENT-->
           <item title="d"></item>                 
        </item> 
       <item title="x">             
           <item title="y"></item> 
           <item title="z"></item>  
       </item>            
   </item> 
</root>
```

Result:

```
<item title="a">...</item>
<item title="b">...</item>
```

Edit:
Answers with axes ancestor are fine. 
My problem was elsewhere, in XSLT

XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="curr" select="//item[@title = 'c']"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="test" select="$curr/ancestor::item"></xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="$test/item">
<xsl:value-of select="@title"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Returns:

```
bcdx
```

---

**Edit2:** for dimitre and for all who have a similar problem

All the answers to my question were good.

Just XSLT (up) returns to me a strange result and @Mads Hansen corrected me.

FINAL WORKING EXAMPLE:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <item title="a">
       <item title="b">               
           <item title="c"></item> 
           <item title="d"></item>                 
        </item> 
       <item title="x">             
           <item title="y"></item> 
           <item title="z"></item>  
       </item>            
   </item> 
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="curr" select="//item[@title = 'c']"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="test" select="$curr/ancestor::item"></xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="$test">
            <xsl:value-of select="@title"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Returns:

```
ab
```

Comment: So, what is the problem with the XSLT code? I see one main problem -- it isn't syntactically valid -- there isn't even a single template in this code. Due to this, no meaningful answers can be given. Please, edit the question and provide a complete (but as small as possible) transformation that can be executed by everyone so that the problem could be reproduced. Also, please, provide the exact expected result and why the result you currently get is a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congradulations to Adam for a very quick first answer.

#### Just to add a little detail:

Your listed expected result does not match your words. the root element also an ancestor node and the document is also an ancestor node.

```
ancestor::node()
```

... will return a sequence in this order:

1. `item[@title='b']`
2. `item[@title='a']`
3. the `root` element (a.k.a. the document element)
4. the [root node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node) `/`

To get the specific result you listed, you need:

```
ancestor::item/.
```

The effect of the /. is to change the ordering back to forward document order. The native order of ancestor:: is reverse document order.

---

## Update: Illustration of points made in the comment feed.

This style-sheet (with OP's input)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//item[@title='c']">
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::item[1]/@title" />
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::item[2]/@title" />
  </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:template>         
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will output 'ba' illustrating the point that ancestor:: is indeed a reverse axis. And yet this style-sheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//item[@title='c']">
    <xsl:value-of select="(ancestor::item/@title)[1]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="(ancestor::item/@title)[2]" />
  </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... has the opposite result 'ab' . This is instructive because it shows that in XSLT 1.0 (not so in XSLT 2.0), the brackets remove the reverse nature, and it becomes a document ordered node-set.

The OP has asked about a transform something like....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//item[@title='c']">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::item">
      <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This one returns 'ab' (in XSLT 2.0 it would return 'ba'). Why? Because in XSLT 1.0, the xsl:for-each instruction ignores the reverse-ness of the axis and processes in document order (unless an xsl:sort instruction says otherwise).

Comment: i have same result with /. and without. <xsl:for-each select="//item[@title = 'c']/ancestor::item"> is the same <xsl:for-each select="//item[@title = 'c']/ancestor::item/."> .. result: ab

Comment: In XPATH 1.0 or 2.0, ancestor:: is indeed a reverse axis (refer http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ section 2.4; and http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/ section 3.2.1.1), **But** how you actually use it XSLT may change the order - and the behaviour depends on XSLT version.  ....

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, an xsl:for-each instruction will ignore the order in the xpath expression, (unless a sort applies). But in XSLT 2.0, the instrinsic order is retained.

Comment: To understand what I mean, try using a positional predicate. Even in XSLT 1.0 using xsl:for-each, you get the reverse order.

Comment: I will post a short piece of XSLT 1.0 to illustrate.

Comment: My statement "Even in XSLT 1.0 using xsl:for-each, you get the reverse order" in earlier comment was very badly worded. Just ignore that one.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to get all ancestors of current node

The designated nodes obviously aren't *all* ancestors of the "green" node.

**To select *all* ancestors use**:

```
ancestor::node()
```

This selects all ancestor nodes of the initial conext node (or current node), including the top element and its parent -- the [root node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node) `/` -- which is a node, but isn't an element.

**To select all *element* ancestors use**:

```
ancestor::*
```

This is similar to the previous expression, but doesn't select the [root node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node) (`/`), because it isn't an element.

**To select all ancestors named `item`, use**:

```
ancestor::item
```

**Do Note**: All expressions above assume that `(//item[@title='c'])[1]` is the initial context node (current node). If this assumption is not correct, then `(//item[@title='c'])[1]/` must be prepended to each of the expressions.

**Note2**: I strongly recommend for learning XPath to use a tool like **[the XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**. For many years this tool has helped many thousands of people learn XPath the fun way -- by playing with XPath expressions and observing the result of their evaluation.

**Note**: The XPath Visualizer was created by me in year 2000 and was never a financial product. I am recommending it based solely on its value to the users, proven in the course of many years

Answer (score 2):

You can use the xpath `ancestor::item`

Comment: Slight error: You need to reverse the order to meet the OP's expectations.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you were outputting `bcdx` instead of `ab` is because your `<xsl:for-each>` is iterating over all of the `item` children of the selected `item` elements, rather than just iterating over the selected elements in the `$test` variable.

**Change your for-each to just iterate over `$test`:**

```
<xsl:variable name="curr" select="//item[@title = 'c']"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="test" select="$curr/ancestor::item"></xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="$test">
    <xsl:value-of select="@title"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:for-each>
```